# CSS attribute and tag attribute

Tags: html, css

I am studying now HTML and CSS. I have this code in CSS:

```
h2 {
    background: url(../_images/open.png) no-repeat 0 11px;
    padding: 10px 0 0 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

This code changes some attribute values of all **h2** tags.

My question is:
How do I know what attributes a tag has, so I can make use of them?

For example, if I use all **h3** tags for example, where (on the Internet) do I find what attributes the tag **h3** has, so I can change them? I may want to change the cursor, but how do I know an **h3** tag even has a cursor attribute?

Something like when using a Button from WindowsForms, I go on MSDN and find all the properties that a Button has and I set them as I want.
I
 checked on w3schools, but could not find anything like that.

Comment: I would advice you to check out http://www.htmldog.com/guides/ for guides / reference work. The official references are located on the w3c sites but you don't want to be digging in there if you're unfamiliar to html. As a side note, w3schools is a terrible place to use as a reference, pretty much any other site is better. Unfortunately your question is subjective and thus does not fit Q&A format because it solicits debate.

Comment: First of all, _every_ CSS property can be applied to _every_ element. If it has any _effect_ might be a different matter. The W3C specifications have an “applies to” section for every property, so go and look it up there when in doubt.

Answer (score 4):

> This code changes some attribute values of all h2 tags.

You appear to be confusing CSS properties with HTML attributes. There is some cross-over between the two, but they should be considered separate things.

> How do I know what <strike>attributes</strike> properties a tag has, so I can make use of them?

You can set **any** CSS property for any element. Some will always apply. Some will apply depending on what other CSS properties are set.

For instance, `left` only applies to elements that are *positioned* (which is defined as *Having a `position` property value other than `static`*).

The element type doesn't matter (beyond the values for properties that are assigned to it from the browser's default stylesheet, and usually the only one that matters there is `display`).

The CSS 2.1 specification a [a list of all the properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/propidx.html)  you can use. CSS Level 3 adds more properties, but they are scattered throughout various specifications. The W3C [has a wiki](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties), but I can't speak for its completeness.

Comment: There does not seem to be any authoritative list of all CSS properties, and it would be difficult to compose one: most CSS Level 3 documents are at draft level, though partly implemented. I have composed a [CSS keyword index](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/css/keywords.html) with about 1,000 entries (but it contains also keywords other than property names and, on the other hand, lists properties without vendor prefixes).

Answer (score 1):

**CSS**

You can apply all css properties to all html elements. How it is rendered and what is supported, depends on the browser. An example would be that you can apply a border to any element (tag).

**Html Attributes**

When it comes to attributes of elements you will have to search the web for each attribute. Find a webpage you think describes the attributes the best (most uses w3school - but a lot is against this page, as some info is outdated). As always, the browser will have to support the attributes. There is no "msdn" for html attributes, so you won't find a complete list.

--

You should note that there is a big difference between css attributes and the attributes of an element.

Comment: Outdated … or just plain wrong.